# Retrieve Forms Authentication Expiration Date/Time

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, forms-authentication

I'm using forms authentication and currently create a forms auth ticket when a user logs in, and set an expiry of about 5 days if they have requested to persist the login.

I now need to create an additional cookie to store some additional settings and IF a user is authenticated, I would like to be able to get the date/time that their forms auth ticket is due to expire, whether the forms ticket is persistent, and set that as the expiry for my other cookie, but I don't know how to get that forms auth expiration date/time or check if it's persistent.

Can this information be extracted from the encrypted forms auth ticket?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [FormsAuthenticationTicket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.aspx).

```
FormsIdentity identity = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity as FormsIdentity;
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = identity.Ticket;
//ticket.Expiration
//ticket.IsPersistent
```

Plus you can get the cookie like:

```
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
```